# perl embed data like in c shell

Tags: perl, shell, command, embed

Is there a way to embed data into a perl script and use/read it later as a temp file in a similar way to c-shell.

```
cat<< eof>tmp.txt
store a multiline text file
eof

run_some_function on [anotherexternalfile] with [tmp.txt]

rm tmp.txt
```

I want to embed multiple set of commands/data files within one perl script to wrap up a set of commands to avoid a requirement for a plethora of external command files.

**Update**

The embeded file/data needs to be read as an input file for another executable function as below.

```
system("executable.exe [anotherexternalfile] [tmp.txt]");
```

Comment: why not use a subroutine to store collections of commands

Comment: and variables for data

Comment: So you want to know how to write to tmp.txt?

Comment: Now you put it like that it sounds far to easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called [here-docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3C%3CEOF), and they are supported by Perl.

```
print <<'__EOI__';
foo
bar
__EOI__

my $x = <<'__EOI__';
foo
bar
__EOI__

for (<<'__EOI__', <<'__EOI__')
foo
bar
__EOI__
abc
def
__EOI__
{
    print;
}
```

Comment: Also note the difference between <<'_HERE_' and <<"_HERE_", the latter which allows variable expansion.

Comment: I placed a link in my node that covered that, but SO is not displaying it. Let's see if I can fix it.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm not sure this is what I was after. It looks like the 'here-docs' works while you are reading the data. I need to read the data as part of another function and as a txt type file.

Answer (score 5):

As I understand, `perl` has the `DATA` handle, where you can keep data to use from the script. This way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

while ( <DATA> ) {
  ## Work with this data as if you were reading it from an external file.
}

__DATA__
some data
more data
and more...
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl has "here documents" http://perl.about.com/od/perltutorials/qt/perlheredoc.htm. And of course Perl can execute external commands just like a shell could: http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands

Answer (score 0):

As per user1937198's suggestions:

```
my @cmds = (
    "cmd1 arg1 arg2",
    "cmd2 arg1 > somefile",
);
for my $cmd (@cmds) {
    system($cmd);
}
```

As a more complete answer to the here-doc:

```
my $cmds = <<CMDS;
cmd1 arg1 arg2
cmd2 arg1 > somefile
CMDS

for my $cmd (split("\n", $cmds)) {
    system("$cmd");
}
```